# Email Send and IERs not appear in CRM Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, email, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm sending an Email from Marketing Cloud within Journey Builder with Salesforce Data Event (Object: Contact; WHO: PersonContactID).
I can't view the Email Send from the 'Email Sends' tab within Sales Cloud, however the 'Individual Email Results' are always 0.
I have tried to make other tests using DEs as Entry Event in JB or Guided Sends in Email Studio (using Salesforce Data Extension) and in these cases I can view Email Send and IERs in Sales Cloud.
So, the issue regards only Salesforce Data Event.
I also have tried to re-establish the connection from Marketing Cloud tab in SF but the issue didn't solved.

Could you help me please in order to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the checkbox on the email send activity that says Send tracking data to Salesforce?

Comment: Hi @zuzannamj, yes i did.